"ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'BaseRepository' before initialization" on page refresh
I have a BaseRepository abstract class in my code which contains client instance and some general functions. The AuthRepository class inherits from BaseRepository. And I have an AuthService module which uses AuthRepository to login and/or check login status. When I open a route I send a request to my API. I use AuthService to check and get token for authorization in client request interceptor. If I can get token for request I add it to headers and continue with request. If I cannot I redirect to login page to login again. It works fine when I first login from my login page and continue using web app but I get the error "ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'BaseRepository' before initialization" if I refresh the page.
BaseRepository
import { BackendClient } from "@/repositories/clients";
import type { AxiosError, AxiosInstance, AxiosResponse } from "axios";

// other imports

export default abstract class BaseRepository {
    protected readonly client: AxiosInstance = BackendClient;
    // general functions
}

AuthRepository
import { BaseRepository } from "@/repositories/base";

class AuthRepository extends BaseRepository {
    constructor() {
        super()
    }
    // other functions
}

const authRepository = new AuthRepository();

export default authRepository;

Axios client
import axios, { type AxiosInstance } from "axios";

import { AuthService } from "@/modules/auth";
import router from "@/router";

import appConfig from "@/config";

const client: AxiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: appConfig.backendClient.baseUrl,
  headers: {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
  },
  validateStatus: (status: number): boolean => {
    var isValid = (status < 400 || status == 401);
    console.log("requestvalidatestatus", isValid);
    return isValid;
  }
})

const TOKEN_EXCLUDE_ENDPOINTS = [
  'Auth/Login',
  'Auth/Register',
  'Auth/RefreshAccessToken'
]

client.interceptors.request.use(async (config) => {
  var requestUrl = config.url;
  for(var excludeEndpoint of TOKEN_EXCLUDE_ENDPOINTS) {
    if(requestUrl?.startsWith(excludeEndpoint)){
      return config;
    }
  }

  var token = await AuthService.getAccessToken();

  if(!token) {
    router.push('/login');
  }
  console.log("token",token);
  config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
  return config;
})

export default client;

AuthService
import { AuthRepository } from "@/repositories";

class AuthService {
    async login(request: LoginRequest, rememberMe: boolean, forceLogin: boolean = false) {
        // other logic
        return await AuthRepository.login(request);
    }
    // other functions
}

const authService = new AuthService();

export default authService;

What might be the problem here?

Almost certainly a circular dependency.

You can see this in the imports. AuthService -> AuthRepository -> BaseRepository -> BackendClient -> AuthService

Likely: You have bundle splitting enabled. When your login page loads, the modules are loaded in a certain order that works, and all is well. When the app is loaded, the modules are loaded in a different order, and AuthRepository tries to load BaseRepository, but it is not initialized yet.

If you absolutely cannot fix this in the usual ways — untangling the dependencies — one solution is to import all of the modules into a single file. This file must not use any of the imports and does not have to do anything — it simply allows you to control the loading order. Whether this will work in your case, I cannot say.

Thanks for the answer, I see the problem more clearly now, it definitilely is a circular dependency issue. I think using factory pattern to lazy-load required repositories and using singleton repository objects might solve this issue. What do you think ?

It was a circular dependency issue. I solved it by implementing request interceptor in main.ts.
main.ts
import { BackendClient } from './repositories/clients'
import { AuthService } from './modules/auth'

const TOKEN_EXCLUDE_ENDPOINTS = [
    'Auth/Login',
    'Auth/Register',
    'Auth/RefreshAccessToken'
]

BackendClient.interceptors.request.use(async (config) => {
    var requestUrl = config.url;
    for (var excludeEndpoint of TOKEN_EXCLUDE_ENDPOINTS) { // Token istemeyen endpoint ise devam et
        if (requestUrl?.startsWith(excludeEndpoint)) {
            return config;
        }
    }

    var token = await AuthService.getAccessToken();

    if (!token) {
        router.push('/login');
    }
    console.log("token", token);
    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
    return config;
})

BackendClient.ts
import axios, { type AxiosInstance } from "axios";

import appConfig from "@/config";

const client: AxiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: appConfig.backendClient.baseUrl,
  headers: {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
  },
  validateStatus: (status: number): boolean => {
    var isValid = (status < 400 || status == 401);
    console.log("requestvalidatestatus", isValid);
    return isValid;
  }
})

export default client;

